# ¿Cómo tener 2 botones submit en formulario?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

tengo un formulario donde inserto registros, un botón me sirve para insertar y otro para generar un PDF "ambos son submit", todo me sale bien ambos botones realizan sus funciones correctamente, el problema que tengo es al utilizar un preloader se carga con ambos botones y yo solo quiero que aparezca con el botón de registrar los datos, bueno esto es un poco del código que utilizo:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Submit para generar el documento pdf:

```
<button type="submit" name="btnImprimir" class="btn btn-warning" formtarget="_blank" formaction="http://localhost/mesadepartes/DocSoliQueja">IMPRIMIR Y FIRMAR</button>
```

Submit para registrar datos:

```
<button type="submit" name="envExpediente" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-color: #666;">ENVIAR EXPEDIENTE </button>
<?php
     $registrarE = new ControladorExpediente();
     $registrarE->ctrRegistrarExpedienteQueja();
     ?>
```

Método para cargar mi modal con el preloader:

```
<script>
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        $("#exampleModalCenter").modal("show");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregar id los name de los buttons y un onclick para identificar cual está llamando:

```
<button type="submit" id="envExpediente" name="envExpediente" onclick="document.querySelector('#envExpediente').classList.add('llameyo')" class="btn btn-primary d-inline-block mx-auto" style="border-color: #666;">ENVIAR EXPEDIENTE </button>
```

Y en el script has de detener el submit e identificar que el button que llama es el del registro:

```
 $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btnSelected = document.querySelector('.llameyo');
        if(btnSelected.id == 'envExpediente'){
            console.log('Llamada del button de registro');
            $("#exampleModalCenter").modal("show");
        }
        this.submit();
    });
```

He agregado que siga el submit al final, pero también puedes hacer que lo dispare el modal, como quieras